# How to crop image into overlapping patches using Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, crop, patch, overlapping

I have an image and I want to extract overlapping patches. Each patch has size of 16x16 and the overlapping pixels is 10. I need to save each extracted patch as an image and rename it with a number. I used the follwing code in Matlab. I need the overlapping pixels to be 10, So, I used the stepsize=10, Is this value of the stepsize means that the overlapping pixels is 10 or I should use another value for the stepsize? I am not sure that this value will perform this task correctly. Can anyone help me on this?

```
% Read input image.
rgbImage = imread('4.png');
figure;imshow(rgbImage);

[rows, columns, numColorChannels] = size(rgbImage);
stepSize = 10;
subImageWidth = 16;

 count=0;
% extract overlapping patches
for row = 1 : stepSize : rows
    row2 = min(row + subImageWidth - 1, rows);

    for col = 1 : stepSize : columns
         col2 = min(col + subImageWidth - 1, columns);
        subImage = rgbImage(row:row2, col:col2, :);

        baseFileName = sprintf('%d.jpg', count);
        Foldername='D:/input patches' ;
        fullFileName = fullfile(Foldername, baseFileName);
        imwrite(subImage, fullFileName);
        count=count+1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Take a look at [`blockproc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html).  The optional `'BorderSize'` input can be used to make the blocks overlapping. It can simplify your code a lot

Comment: I took a look at blockproc. however, I don't know how to use it for my task.. I want to make overlapping cropping to obtain patches of 16x16 from the image. could you help me on that?

Comment: Here's a quick example. The file name will include the coordinates of its upperleft corner, rather than a sequential index. `borderSize = repelem((subImageWidth-stepSize)/2, 2); blockproc(rgbimage, [stepSize stepSize], @(x)imwrite(x.data, [num2str(x.location) '.jpg']), 'BorderSize', borderSize);`

Answer (score 0):

`stepSize = 10` gives an overlap of 6 pixels. For example the 2nd image starts at `column=11`, so the overlapping columns are 11 to 16. Try

```
stepSize = subImageWidth-overlap
```

with

```
overlap=10
```

The rest of the code looks OK.

Comment: however, this format gives an overlap of 9 pixels. For example , if stepSize= subImage-overlap+1 = 16-10+1=7, then the 2nd image starts at column=8, so the overlapping columns are 8 to 16 which is 9 pixels. I think in this case, The best option is using stepSize=subImageWidth - overlap.

Comment: @GhadaSandoub OOPS! You are right. I modified the answer accordingly. Thank you.